# GTK get multiple range value segmentation error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, range, gtk, gtk3

So, I'm trying to create an rgb selector with gtk in C.

I follow the documentation to learn how to put in place a glade project and use it with gtk, so I made an UI in glade, but I have some trouble with the GTK part. I need to have access to multiple slider in the change-value signal because I want to get their value to print them, so I have created a struct to stock them, and I send this struct in the signal. But my problem is when I try to get the value of the range which his stock in the struct I have a segmentation error and I don't know why. I tried without the struct and I can correctly get the slider value, but it didn't work with the struct. How can I fix it?

Ask me if you need the glade file too.

```c
//Compil : gcc -rdynamic -o ColorPicker colorPicker.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib/gstdio.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>

typedef struct
{
    GObject *redSlider;
    GObject *blueSlider;
    GObject *greenSlider;
    GObject *label;
}Data;


static void changeLabel (GtkWidget *range, Data *data)
{
    gdouble red = gtk_range_get_value(GTK_RANGE(data->redSlider));
    g_print("%.0lf\n",red);
    //g_print("R : %d, G : %d, B : %d",red,green,blue);

}


static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{

    Data *data;
    data = malloc(sizeof(*data));

    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "colorPicker.glade",NULL);

    GObject *window = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window");
    gtk_window_set_application (GTK_WINDOW (window), app);


    data->redSlider = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "redSlider");
    g_signal_connect (data->redSlider, "change-value", G_CALLBACK (changeLabel), (gpointer) data);

    data->blueSlider = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "blueSlider");
    g_signal_connect (data->blueSlider, "change-value", G_CALLBACK (changeLabel), (gpointer) data);

    data->greenSlider = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "greenSlider");
    g_signal_connect (data->greenSlider, "change-value", G_CALLBACK (changeLabel), (gpointer) data);

    data->label = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "cpChooseLabel");

    /*GObject *colorBtn = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "colorBtn");
    g_signal_connect (colorBtn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (getColor), (gpointer) data);*/
    
    gtk_widget_show (GTK_WIDGET (window));

    /* We do not need the builder any more */
    g_object_unref (builder);
    free(data);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
#ifdef GTK_SRCDIR
    g_chdir(GTK_SRCDIR);
#endif
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("com.github.XXXXXX.rgbSelector", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);

    int status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You end the structure's lifetime by `free`ing it at the end of `activate`. When the callback `changeLabel` is invoked at some time later, it tries to access the no longer existing structure. You could just drop the `free(data);` if you don't care that the space occupied by the four pointers can't be freed then; another possibility is to simply use a static structure and pass its address.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to drop the free but I continue to get the segmentation error. How would you implement a static structure?

Comment: Hm - I'm afraid that if letting the data structure stay alive still leaves an error, a static structure won't do better; but if you want to try anyway: `Data *data;
    data = malloc(sizeof(*data));` becomes `static Data data;`, `data->` becomes `data.` and `(gpointer) data` becomes `(gpointer)&data`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and as you said before it won't work, I'll try to recreate a struct with an another post I found about sending multiple data in a signal. Thanks for all.